# Boost Sockets message exchange c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am currently trying to create a server to client connection to send XML documents. It appears that it is possible to send these documents after serializing them. My plan is to establish a connection, send one message from client to the server (a list of filters) and then send N messages from the server side when a message meets the filters criterias.

However, before getting to that, I wanted to try a simple implementation of this using only strings to see how it works and to get a better understanding of the boost asio library.

I then implemented my server part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    const int BACKLOG_SIZE = 30;
    unsigned short PORT = 3333;

    // Endpoint and io_service creation
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(),PORT);
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, ep.protocol());

    // Binding to client
    acceptor.bind(ep);

    acceptor.listen(BACKLOG_SIZE);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ios);
    // accepting connection (blocking process) 
    acceptor.accept(socket);

    std::cout << "Binded" << std::endl;

    // Receiving data from client

    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, sb, ec))
    {
        std::cout << "received: " << &sb << "\n";
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "status: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    // Sending data to client

    socket.send("Filters received!");

}
```

and my client part:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string raw_ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
    unsigned short port_num = 3333;
    std::string FILTER = "ATL";

    try {
        // Endpoint creation
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint
            ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(raw_ip_address),
                port_num);

        boost::asio::io_service ios;

        // Creating and opening a socket.
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios, ep.protocol());

        // Connecting a socket.
        sock.connect(ep);

        // Sending data to server

        std::cout << "Connected to " << raw_ip_address << " Port: " << port_num << std::endl;

        sock.send(boost::asio::buffer(FILTER));

        boost::asio::streambuf sb;
        boost::system::error_code ec;

        // Receiving data from server

        while (boost::asio::read(socket, sb, ec))
        {
            std::cout << "received: " << &sb << "\n";
            if (ec)
            {
                std::cout << "status: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Overloads of asio::ip::address::from_string() and 
    // asio::ip::tcp::socket::connect() used here throw
    // exceptions in case of error condition.
    catch (boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << e.code()
            << ". Message: " << e.what();

        return e.code().value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I first started with only sending the filters from the client to the server and it all worked well.
However when I tried adding the response from the server to the client, it caused an error which I don't really understand: error

[image]

As anyone faced this issue and know how to solve it? Is it even possible to establish a connection like that where both side of the socket can send messages as they want (as I said the idea will be to have the server sending N messages coming from another application, after receiving the filters list).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should always post error as text instead of image on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: string literals are not a buffer (or buffer sequence).

You need to describe the buffer, e.g. like so:

```
std::string response("Filters received!");
socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(response));
```

There are many ways. E.g. not using a temporary, you could use a string view literal:

```
socket.send(boost::asio::buffer("Filters received!"sv));
```

---

Second problem:

```
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, sb, ec)) {
```

This cannot work, because you meant `sock`, not `socket` (which exists, but is [`::socket`, type `int(&)(int,int,int)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html).

That said, it's not very useful to read-to-EOF in a while loop, since the loop will **always** break with EOF (or another error).

Finally, because currently, client will never close the socket until a response is received, there will be an indefinite waiting of both programs. Consider a partial shutdown:

```
    sock.send(asio::buffer(FILTER));
    sock.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
```

Here are client and server combined

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6db1fc37fc812ab4)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

static const std::string raw_ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
static const std::string FILTER         = "ATL";
static const int         BACKLOG_SIZE   = 30;
static const uint16_t    PORT           = 3333;

int main(int argc, char**) {
    asio::io_service ios;
    asio::streambuf  sb;
    error_code       ec;

    try {
        if (argc > 1) { // client
            tcp::endpoint ep({}, PORT);

            tcp::socket sock(ios, ep.protocol());
            sock.connect(ep);

            // Sending data to server
            std::cout << "Connected to " << sock.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            sock.send(asio::buffer(FILTER));
            sock.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);

            read(sock, sb, ec);
            std::cout << "received: " << &sb << "\n"
                      << "status: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        } else // server
        {
            tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, tcp::v4());
            acceptor.bind({{}, PORT});
            acceptor.listen(BACKLOG_SIZE);

            tcp::socket sock(ios);
            acceptor.accept(sock);

            std::cout << "Accepted " << sock.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            read(sock, sb, ec);
            std::cout << "received: " << &sb << "\n"
                      << "status: " << ec.message() << "\n";

            sock.send(asio::buffer("Filters received!"sv));
        }
    } catch (boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << e.code()
                  << ". Message: " << e.what() << "\n";

        return 1; // e.code().value() not very useful, as the category is lost
    }
}
```

Run and build with e.g.

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -isystem /usr/local/include/ 
./a.out&
sleep 1; ./a.out client
```

Prints e.g.

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1:3333
Accepted 127.0.0.1:50816
received: ATL
status: End of file
received: Filters received!
status: End of file
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue on sending back messages. I splitted the code so that I can run both server and client on separate codes. However, without the while loop on the read function, I can't ask the client side to wait for additional messages from the server. The idea of this asynchronous message exchange is for the client to wait for possible message from the server and to treat each of them individualy whenever one is available. From what I understand here, even if I send 3 messages, all 3 will be received at the same moment by the client. (I corrected my comment to be more precise)

Comment: You can't anyways because you haven't defined "message" - and your read never completes until the sending end shuts down the connection. Also, your message exchange is synchronous.

Comment: If you want framing, define framing. E.g.: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95a8a52573f29dba

Comment: And here's the whole thing async, with multiple concurrent clients in one program: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cdb0ef5c6e0c542